# -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory issue when installing jasper report server ce from source

Tags: java, maven-3, jasperserver

Im getting this error message:

> [java] -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check
>    $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.

I have already deleted the variable named `$M2_HOME` from the environment variables.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Sounds like you need to add and configure the variable properly.  I'm not familiar with Jasper, but solely based on your error you need to have `$M2_HOME` set, and it needs to have the correct values.

Comment: Its the same as $MAVEN_HOME ... and in path I added these two variables plus \bin for each one.

Answer (score 0):

`maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory` seems like a new command line option in maven-3.3.3. maven-3.1.1 does not require this so you can use that to build ce server. You can also modify the `buildomatic/bin/dev.xml` at about line 162 and add

```
<sysproperty key="maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory" value="@{dir}"/>.
```

This will help the build succeed.